# Im trying to make a Instagram reel downloader and keep getting this error Expecting "property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Tags: json, django

Im using django to create a instagram reel downloader but it keeps giving me json errors

My code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect
from instascrape import *
import json
import time
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "index.html")
    else:
        if request.POST['url']:
            google_reel = Reel("https://www.instagram.com/reel/CumvX9VgNQt/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link&igshid=MzRlODBiNWFlZA==")
            google_reel.scrape()
            google_reel.Download(fp = "{path\filename.mp4}")
        else:
            return render(request, "index.html", {
                    "error": "Invalid url"
                })
    return redirect("/")
```

The error im getting is "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"

im thinking it is a python package problem  the one im using is instascrape (https://github.com/chris-greening/instascrape)

Comment: Does your code (the three lines starting with google_reel) work in a custom script to begin with ?